# CSS drop down menu with different color

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS drop down menu working in the following way:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Monkey 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS:

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover{
    color: #87a0b4;
    background: #fff;
}
ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 100; /* display the dropdown */
}
```

This works perfectly, however I want I something different. I want the drop down menu to have different background and hover colors. also I want the drop down menu to be offset from the that it appears from. How is it that I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify in which elements want to apply style changes.

This one selects first submenu:

```
ul > li:first-child > ul > li a:hover{
    color: #87a0b4;
    background: yellow;
}
```

This one selects the second submenu:

```
ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul > li a:hover{
    color: #87a0b4;
    background: blue;
}
```

This one changes `Link1` hover color:

```
ul > li:first-child a:hover{
    color: #87a0b4;
    background: blue;
}
```

You can continue and apply any effect you want. Hope it helps :)

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g9v49/3/)

Comment: How would I access the only the link that is the head of the drop down?

Answer (score 0):

ul li - targets main menu list items

ul li ul li - targets sub-menu list items

To change the styling of the submenu. You can use something like this.

```
ul li ul li {
    background-color:red;
}
ul li ul li a {
    color:green;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2Nh47/